# Variable has correct value but 'uninitialized value' warning is shown

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

There is a hash containing some data, whose users section is of my interest.

```
my %users = %{$data{'users'}};
foreach my $user_key (keys %users){
        print Dumper $users{$user_key};
        my $mailtime      =  $users{$user_key}{'mail_time'};
        my $id_local       =  $users{$user_key}{'id_local'};
        my $id_global      =  $users{$user_key}{'id_global'};
        print $mailtime;
}
```

everything works properly except the thrown warning at the line `print $mailtime`.
Even the print command would output a correct value along with the nonsense warning, as follows.

```
Use of uninitialized value $mailtime in print at custom_log.pl line 51.
```

The output of the dumper is:

```
$VAR1 = {                                                    
          'id_local' => '0',                                 
          'mail_time' => '1117579067',                       
          'id_global' => '2'                                 
        };
```

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $mail in print at ...` at  the line `print $mailtime;`

Comment: Are you sure that `mail_time` is set for every user? Is the warning given for every iteration of the loop or just for specific `$user_key`?

Comment: @Mat: Yes, of course. Done that.

Comment: It would also help to see the structure of `%data`. Edit: most likely one (or more) of your users has an undefined `mail_time` value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve <= please provide this, chameleon error messages cannot be trusted.

Comment: It's gonna take some time, I am working on an mcve ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing a dump of `%data` it's impossible to see why it's failing, however a little testing suggests one of your users is missing the `mail_time` key. If I create `%data` as follow and run your script...

```
my %data = (
    users => {
        user1 => {
            id_local  => '0',
            mail_time => '1117579067',
            id_global => '2',
        },
        user2 => {
            id_local  => '0',
            # purposely missing mail_time <---
            id_global => '2',
        },
    },
);
```

Then I get the same problem you are having... Output as follows

```
Use of uninitialized value $mailtime in print at custom_log.pl line 27.
1117579067
```

Comment: That was true, Thank you for your help.

Comment: When mysterious problems arise, put in a special debugging statement, like "print STDERR "UNDEFINED mailtime: $user_key\n" if ! $mailtime;  Maybe even do a full dump of the element.

Answer (score 0):

i like perl, cause you have to be precise.
Try to read out your value with:

```
print $users{$user_key}->{'mail_time'};
```

resp.

```
my $mailtime = $users{$user_key}->{'mail_time'};
```

or eventually

```
print $users->{$user_key}->{'mail_time'};
```

I don't now exactly the structure of your hash, but i supposed the first example should works for you, the second one is just for the case. The next time, please Dump the root-hash, in your case  "$data{'user'}" to see the whole structure of it. Further it is not bad to use the perl-debugger, which gives your more informations, just simple with "perl -d scriptname.pl". Good luck and cheers ;-).